# Creating a self-signed certificate in .pem format on windows via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl

I want to create a certificate in .pem format in a script. But I need some help there. I used a Powershell script to generate a certificate in the Windows store; then, I exported it as pfx and tried to convert that to the pem format.
I am confused about why Windows doesn't have a built-in feature, but it is as it is.

That is my script as far:

```
Import-Module PSPKI

Write-Host "Create Windows Certificate"

$paramsCreate = @{
    DnsName = 'localhost'
    CertStoreLocation = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
}
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @paramsCreate


Write-Host "Create Password"
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String '1234' -Force -AsPlainText


Write-Host "Export Certificate as Pfx"
$paramsExport = @{
    Cert = $cert
    FilePath = 'C:\temp.pfx'
    Password = $mypwd
}
Export-PfxCertificate @paramsExport

Write-Host "Convert pfx to pem"
Convert-PfxToPem -InputFile 'C:\temp.pfx' -Password $mypwd -Outputfile 'C:\tmp.pem'

(Get-Content 'C:\tmp.pem' -Raw) -match "(?ms)(\s*((?<privatekey>-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----.*?-
----END PRIVATE KEY-----)|(?<certificate>-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*?-----END CERTIFICATE-----))\s*){2}"

$Matches["privatekey"] | Set-Content "C:\key.pem"
$Matches["certificate"] | Set-Content "C:\cert.pem"
```

I think of what the problem is. This is the error message:

```
Invalid provider type specified
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSPKI\4.0.0\Client\Convert-PfxToPem.ps1:141 char:9
+         throw New-Object ComponentModel.Win32Exception ([Runtime.Inte ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Invalid provider type specified
```

I appreciate any help, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-powershell/

And: https://4sysops.com/archives/create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-powershell/

Use OpenSSL to convert a PFX certificate to PEM format.

```
# Export the private key
openssl pkcs12 -in C:\temp.pfx -nocerts -out C:\key.pem

# Export the certificate
openssl pkcs12 -in C:\temp.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out C:\cert.pem
```

Comment: If this solution worked for you please accept it so that others may find it easier.

Comment: A hint: The flag --nodes on the OpenSSL is useful when the receiver can't handle a password for the cert key. NODES stands for No Data Encryption Standard.